# How to design Menubar as per permissions

Tags: jsp, menubar, user-permissions, database-permissions

I have a application and in that, I have permission form. I am assigning permission as per jsp forms to user.If any user has permission to access the form, that form will be added to menu bar after login. I dont know how to do it. Can someone provide me any link?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used a similar application 
Here system validates the user_group in which a user falls at the time of login.
All the links are maintained in DB with group_id and dynamically loaded after login and maintaned throghout the session.

Comment: You should try and add some detail and maybe some code to provide an answer.

Comment: I too was thinking to have user group and give permission accordingly. But giving permission per page would be one time setting. And will be best for all applications.